# How to determine the source of a log in LogCat?

Tags: android, logging, logcat

Is it possible to determine the location in code, where a particular message was written to LogCat?
I would like to have something like a stack trace for each log, since some logs are of unknown source.

Comment: try using `Timber` library. It also prints the class name from where the log has been printed.

Comment: @Yashasvi well I cant, because It is not me who is printing but rather a library

Comment: Do you have that library's source code?

Comment: @Yashasvi No I dont. I am calling that library on many places in my code and I would like to know which of these calls caused the library to print the message.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Android Debug or simply try to show Log.v("Your messsage"+your response) where ever needed. So that you can get idea where your application reached at that particular time when that Log prints on your LogCat

Comment: I have a weird problem that shows up seemingly randomly and not in debug mode. On crash a library I use writes a log and I would like to know where that happens.